# Pass password for Vimeo private video

Tags: java, android, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm showing  the video in my app, but that video is private so it required password. Is any way to pass password via code or any other way so that password screen wont come? Basically I want that only my app user can see that video. Any other alternative for this?

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question). Stack Overflow's answer acceptance mechanism takes care of identifying answered questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enter a password via code. For this use case Vimeo offers the "Hide from Vimeo" aka "Disabled" privacy setting. It means that it is private on vimeo, but public via embeds.

Comment: its available for normal a\c? if we pass the link will it play ?